# Django can't find table, that exists in postgreSQL database

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm new to database programming, apologies if I ask something simply.

I newly add few tables into my DB use Django model and migrations, now I'm using python bring data and print on scripts

Now to point of my error:

```
DB is connected successfully
Failed to execute database program
relation "cgi_limit" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM CGI_limit
                      ^
connection of DB had close successfully
```

now I check twice on naming. I try others tables such as `auth_user` and its was able print the table contents and I check to see if table exit in my DB as shown below;

```
Farm=# SELECT * FROM pg_tables;
         schemaname     |         tablename          | tableowner | tablespace | hasindexes | hasrules | hastriggers | rowsecurity
     public             | django_session             | FAT        |            | t          | f        | f           | f
     public             | auth_permission            | FAT        |            | t          | f        | t           | f
     public             | auth_user_user_permissions | FAT        |            | t          | f        | t           | f
     public             | auth_user                  | FAT        |            | t          | f        | t           | f
     public             | django_admin_log           | FAT        |            | t          | f        | t           | f
     public             | CGI_ambient                | FAT        |            | t          | f        | f           | f
     public             | CGI_tank_system            | FAT        |            | t          | f        | f           | f
     public             | CGI_limit                  | FAT        |            | t          | f        | f           | f
```

I my python code that render the DB;

```
#import liberys 
import psycopg2 as pg2
from datetime import timedelta, datetime, date

############################################
# Function codes
def getDbConnection():
    #Get Database connection
    try:
        connection =pg2.connect(user='FAT',
                             password='*******',
                             host='',
                             port='5432',
                             database='Farm') 
        print ("DB is connected succefully")
        return connection
    except(Exception, pg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print("Failed to connect to database")

def closeDbConnection(connection):
    #Close Database connection
    try:
        connection.close()
        print("connection of DB had close succefully")
    except(Exception, pg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print("Failed to close database connection")

def DisplayDBdata():
    try:
        connection = getDbConnection()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query = 'SELECT * FROM "CGI_limit"' 

        cursor.execute(query,)
        records = cursor.fetchall()

        for row in records:
            print("date: = ", row[1])

    except(Exception, pg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print("Failed to execute database program")
        print(error)


    finally:
            closeDbConnection(connection)


#############################################################
#code to be excuted
#DeleteDBdata()
DisplayDBdata() #for testing only

#end of code thats excute
```

I'm stump of what I should do. I did some google search and result only naming

I appreciate if you could help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres does not like capitalized table names. You will need to put the table name in quotes to make it work. I would recommend sticking with lowercase names.

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM "CGI_limit"'
```

[Documentation link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html)

Comment: I try that, it given me invalid syntax

Comment: Can you post the exact line it gave you the syntax error on?

Comment: `query = SELECT * FROM "cgi_limit"`

Comment: query = 'SELECT * FROM "CGI_limit"'

Comment: no more syntax error but, i'm still getting the same error `"cgi_limit" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM CGI_limit`

Comment: Did you copy paste the line I provided? Could you update the code in the question to show what you currently are trying.

Comment: ..... as you said Joshua I copy your code and paste in the python and it works. What could be root cause of all this?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation link I provided it goes thru needing to quote any names that need to be used literally otherwise Postgres automatically assumes the name to be lowercase.

Comment: Saved my day..!